# How to convert array of objects to object made up of only values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have [ { key1:value1, key2:value2 }, { key3:value3, key4:value4 }, .... ]. I want to convert it to
{ value1: value2, value3: value4 }

Comment: Have a look at [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Comment: Thanks didn't knew about Array.reduce and Object.values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the inner objects always have 2 keys:

```js
const arr = [ { key1:'value1', key2:'value2' }, { key3:'value3', key4:'value4' }]

const obj = {};

for (const innerObj of arr) {
  const values = Object.values(innerObj);
  obj[values[0]] = values[1];
}

console.log(obj) // { value1: 'value2', value3: 'value4' }
```

Note: you're question assumes an order for the keys in the inner objects, but that may not be guaranteed

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate your object-data. Foreach object take from the values the first and add a new property with this name to the accumulated object with the value from the second object-value.

```js
let array = [ { key1:'value1', key2:'value2' }, { key3:'value3', key4:'value4' }];

let res = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    values = Object.values(cur);
    acc[values[0]] = values[1];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```